# ¿Como detectar cuado cambia el texto del p?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito averiguar cuando se cambia un texto para mostrar todos sus cambios en otro p, he probado a hacerlo con el evento change y con focus:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#p");
const pfinal = document.querySelector("#pfinal");
pfinal.textContent= p.textContent;
p.contentEditable="true";

p.addEventListener("change", cambio);
function cambio(){
console.log("Ni siquiera se ejecuta");
    pfinal.textContent= p.textContent;
}

p.addEventListener("focus", focus);
function focus(){
console.log("Se ejecuta solo la primera vez");
   pfinal.textContent= p.textContent;
}
```

```html
<p id ="p">Texto</p>
<p id="pfinal"></p>
```

El evento change no se ejecuta y no entiendo porque, mientras que el focus solo se ejecuta la primera vez y no mientras se se cambia. ¿Hay algun otro evento que pueda usar para que se ejecute cada vez que cambia el texto?

PD: necesito que los dos p NO esten envueltos por ningun otro elemento.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) no se ejecuta cuando se modifica el contenido de un elemento.

Para poder detectar este tipo de cambio podes utlizar la API [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const p = document.querySelector("#p");
const pfinal = document.querySelector("#pfinal");
pfinal.textContent = p.textContent;
p.contentEditable = "true";

// Opciones para el observer (que mutaciones observar)
const config = {
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
};

// Función callback que se ejecuta en cada mutación
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "characterData") {
      console.log("El texto ha cambiado ");
    }
  }
};

//
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(p, config);

p.addEventListener("focus", focus);

function focus() {
  console.log("Se le dio foco");
  pfinal.textContent = p.textContent;
}
```

```html
<p id="p">Texto</p>
<p id="pfinal"></p>
```